# Square root of negative $i$

Tags: complex-numbers

What will be the square root of negative $i$

$\sqrt{-i}$

Will it be $i$ multiplied by root $i$, or something different?

Here is my thinking:

$\sqrt{-i} = \sqrt{-1\cdot i} = i\cdot \sqrt{i}$

Comment: Do you know the geometric interpretation of complex numbers (the complex plane), and what multiplication looks like in that interpretation?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that while $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt x \sqrt y$ is an identity for real $x$ and $y$, it is not true in general when $x$ and $y$ are complex.

Comment: Iota is $\iota$, without the dot. One needs to specify what $\sqrt{\cdot}$ means in the context because it has branches at every point.

Comment: The imaginary unit it's not called iota ($\iota$), it's called just $i$.

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Avoid the use of images.

Comment: Well, you are correct but in the following sense: whatever be the value(s) of $\sqrt{i} $, multiplying it(them) by $i$ gives the value(s) of $\sqrt{-i}$.

Comment: Also you can get the roots using memory. Just remember $(1\pm i) ^2=\pm 2i$.

Comment: Ya, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the square **roots** (plural) of $-i$ as follows:

Let $(a+b\,i)^2 = -i$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Then $a^2-b^2+2ab\,i = -i$.

From here we have $a^2-b^2 = 0$ and $2ab=-1$. Lets solve this system.

The first equation gives $a=b$ or $a=-b$, but the first case can't happen since $2ab=-1$. So we have $a=-b$.

The second equation gives $2a(-a)=-1$ so $a=\pm\sqrt{1/2}$.

The solutions of the system are $(a,b)=(\sqrt{1/2},-\sqrt{1/2})$ and $(a,b)=(-\sqrt{1/2},\sqrt{1/2})$ and then the square roots of $-i$ are $$\sqrt{1/2}- i\sqrt{1/2}$$ and $$-\sqrt{1/2}+ i\sqrt{1/2}$$
as you can check by squaring this numbers.

Answer (score -1):

We can write $\sqrt{-i}$ as $e^{\frac{1}{2} \ln (-i)}$. The complex logarithm is
$$\ln (z) = \ln(||z||) + i \arg(z)$$
Where $||.||$ is the modulus function and $\arg$ is the angle in which the complex number $z$ is.
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{-i} = e^{\frac{1}{2} (\ln(1) + i \arg(-i))}$$
If the branch we're working with is $(-\pi, \pi)$, then $\arg(-i) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{-i} = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}} = \cos \Big(\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) - i \sin \Big(\frac{\pi}{4} \Big)$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{-i} = \pm \Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.